# Thread.CurrentPrincipal Identity.Name is null in asp.net mvc 6 (vNext)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am developing a web application using Asp.Net MVC6 (vNext), Identity 3.0.* beta3. This is 3-tier application with UI, Services and DB. I am able to sign in user with `SignInManager` class of Asp.net identity, and I am trying to retrieve user details with roles & claims in the service layer so that I can verify if user has permission to take certain actions.

How do we get Current username from current request principal identity in the service layer. In MVC 5, I have used `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` to do this. But in MVC6 `Identity.Name` of `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` is set to null.

Can someone let me know how I can do this?  Also, if you have any better solution, please let me know.

Comment: I know that the HttpApplication object set thread's principal to the HttpContext's when it acquires a thread. Did you try the HttpContext.Current.User, is null also?

Comment: @RazvanDumitru Thank for reply. Can you let me know how to get HttpContext in the Service layer ?

Comment: ASP.Net 5 is written in a manner as to be fully unit testable, with as few static properties as possible. As such, values such as the user's principal should be passed into your Service layer as a parameter. (This isn't really an answer, but a recommendation to follow accepted design patterns instead.) In addition, with the way `async` is changing things, thread-specific information could be lost.

Comment: @MattDeKrey is right. You should always pass your context data & user info data (especially) and all values that you need to the service layer as a parameter.

Answer (score 3):

If you've called `AddIdentity()` in your Startup.cs or wherever you configure your dependency injection, it will automatically register a singleton `HttpContextAccessor` as satisfying the `IHttpContextAccessor` service.

At this point, in your service layer, you can inject `IHttpContextAccessor` and retrieve the context from there.  This assumes that you understand how the Dependency Injection system works and are using it to instantiate your service layer classes rather than just `new`ing them.

If you want to be able to conveniently access the `Id` or `Name` of the `ClaimsPrincipal` that's exposed in the `HttpContext` make sure that you import `System.Security.Claims` so that you have access to the extensions that provide you with the `GetUserName()` and `GetUserId()` extension methods.

(This is up-to-date as of the `beta4` packages that were released with VS2015 RC1)

Comment: I would even recommend taking this one step further and completely remove any mention of anything `HttpContext` related from your code, since all you REALLY want is a service that gives you the current `ClaimsPrincipal`.  Make an `ICurrentClaimsPrincipal` interface that exposes an `CurrentPrincipal` property.  Create a class that implements it, that uses the `IHttpContextAccessor` dependency to read the current principal and return it from the `CurrentPrincipal` property.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you can pass access services in your layer, the equivalent of HttpContext.Current is [IHttpContextAccessor.HttpContext](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.Interfaces/IHttpContextAccessor.cs) which is a service exposed by the hosting layer.

Answer (score 1):

May be there is better way. But for now I am adding a custom middleware as in below code to inject ussername in current thread in startup.cs class. And in the service layer I will read it using Thread.GetData(Thread.GetNamedDataSlot("current-username")).

```
public class Startup {

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerfactory)
    {

        //.... code

        app.UseIdentity();

        //... more code

        app.Use(async (ctx, next) =>
        {
            var httpContext = (ctx as HttpContext);
            if (httpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                Thread.SetData(Thread.GetNamedDataSlot("current-username"), httpContext.User.Identity.Name);
            }
            await next();
        });

        //... more code

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller}/{action}/{id?}",
                    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
            });

    }
}
```

Comment: Writing your own security related code is fraught with danger. 

E.g. here, if an authenticated user makes a request, they end up in the thread slot. If an unauthenticated user then makes a request and it happens upon the same thread, you don't clear out the username, so they will still be authenticated as the first user == you've just opened yourself up to being hacked.

If (!httpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) then....
    clear the thread authentication slot

Comment: Thanks Jon. I am actually clearing the slot after I read it in the service layer. I only need username once per request. But you raised good piont. I wish there is better way to do this.

Comment: Also, using thread static data like this, directly, is going to result in sadness as soon as you start using async methods.  You've now also made your service layer more difficult to test by having it directly access thread local data, rather than declaring a dependency on an IHttpContextAccessor that can be mocked.